# Theano - iteration using scan vs for loop

Tags: python, performance, theano

What are advantages/disatvantages of iterating using scan vs for loop in Theano? How big of a difference does it make to use/not use GPU?

I'm aware of the fact that using `scan` is generally more restrictive, as it for example would be impossible to plot errors for each iteration.

What interests me the most are the performance consequences of compiling against reusing function - I've made [a notebook](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/stackexchange/blob/master/stackoverflow/Scan.ipynb) where I timed function using scan and one that is just iterating in Python, and the results seem puzzling (is compiling `scan`'s graph really independent of its length, at least for some big constant?).